# Error with returning the result of function

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am getting this error - "Return outside function" in Jupyterlab. What can I do to make my word cloud out of .text file?

[The code and its error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAku.png)

I am getting this error as I started with my code to make a word cloud out of a txt file.
What can be done?

Comment: I'm not voting you down. but it's because you write return outside of the function. can't you see that?

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image. Python uses indentation to define code blocks. The `return ...` needs to be indented at the same level as the rest of the function, otherwise python thinks is a statement for the outer block. In your case, since the outer block is not in a function and return needs to be in a function, you get the error.

Comment: had you posted text, we could copy/fix/paste but who wants to transcribe an image?

Answer (score 0):

A function cannot be split between two different cells in JupyterLab.
Your complete function must be in one cell, so just putting the return in the above cell, with the rest of your function, should work.

Comment: I don't use jupyter. Is it easy to describe how to put code in a different cell? if OP indented the statement, would that automatically make it part of the cell?

Comment: No. Indenting the return would just make the return indented, but still in its own individual cell. 
Yes, he needs to add an indent too, but Jupyter won't know that the return belongs to the function in the other cell if he keeps it there.

Comment: I think when some question votes down with more than one in its ten minutes of posting, that post will be deleted soon and nobody shall make answers for it. You can give hints or comments in the comment section. It's possible that the answer gets vote down too. regards.

Comment: This is a tricky case when the question asked by the beginner is showing low effort (screenshot instead of copy-paste code which annoys people, hence downvotes) and seems like duplicate of a duplicate, but in fact the answer contains a very important advice for absolute beginners, which I don't think was mentioned in what would have appeared to be duplicates but are not (these often involve using `return` in `while` etc).